# heroku 2 errors while trying to get my discord bot up and running

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack, discord.js

so I've received 2 errors whole trying to get my bot to run on heroku

```
021-10-26T08:02:07.109272+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109272+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109272+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109273+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109273+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109273+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109273+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.109273+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-10-26T08:02:07.228855+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-26T08:02:07.425786+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

now i am not really sure what these errors mean so any help is welcomed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mind sending the full error message, as that doesnt show the origin of the problem

Comment: I'm also having this problem - with identical logs...